# Resolve error "Required Media Missing" for tape backup

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, tape, tapedrive

I just recently bought 8 brand new tapes for the purposes of backing up my data to tape drives. I put in one of the brand new tapes in the drive and opened up Backup Utility because this is the program i was instructed to use. I stepped through the hoops on setting up the media for a recurring backup and when I went to execute the backup for the first time I received the following message...

> Required Media Missing There is no
>   free media available with the selected
>   type. Add unused media or click Cancel
>   to end the operation. Note: It may
>   take up to 60 seconds to recognize new
>   media.

Remember I have inserted a brand new tape for this process. What could possibly be going wrong? I did run across [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239892) however that says I need to prepare the media. I follow these steps and when I right-click on the media to select "prepare" the only option that shows up is "free." In otherwords I cant even prepare my media for backup utility to use properly.

Any suggestions or solutions? This has been way more of a hassle than I have anticipated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you free the tape and run the backup from the Backup utility, it should recognize the new tapes in the Free media pool (where they go when you "free" them).